# Swift - NSContiguousString memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

memory leak in the code at line,

```
cellDescriptor.setValue(data, forKey: kValuePlistKey)
```

So how to fix this memory leak ? this leak getting again and again ? leaking memory approx 1mb

Comment: If you have found the solution thereafter, consider sharing it

Comment: Anyone found a solution? This seems like a bug with this NSContiguousString type and UIKit.